# How to set default first item in drop down list - angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

My drop-down contains a list of action ids and names of operations as shown below.

```
{ id: 0, name: 'Select Operation' },
{ id: 1, name: 'Operation 1' },
{ id: 2, name: 'Operation 2' },
{ id: 3, name: 'Operation 3' },
{ id: 4, name: 'Operation 4' }
```

Initially, a user can see 'Select Operation' option in the web application.

After selecting an operation from the drop-down list according to the operation that opens the respective operating model window, and after closing that window, the user should see "Select operation", not the previously selected operation element.
Basically I'm new to Angular and not getting any idea how to achieve this. If any idea please help me to achieve this.

**This is my html:**

```
<div class="bx--row">
    <div class="bx--col-md-3"></div>

    <div class="bx--col-md-1">
        <select id="select-menu" class="bx--text-input" required name="actionSelection" (change)="onActionChange($event)"
            (dblclick)="onActionChange($event)">
            <option *ngFor="let action of actions" [value]="action.id">{{action.name}}</option>
        </select>

        <carbon-modal [modalId]="modalid" [modalTitle]="modaltitle" [isFull]="isFull">
            <div modal-body>
                <div *ngIf="Operation1">
                    <Operation1></Operation1>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="Operation2">
                    <Operation2></Operation2>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="Operation3">
                    <Operation3></Operation3>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="Operation4">
                    <Operation4></Operation4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </carbon-modal>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use ngModel to archive this.

Answer (score 1):

this can be achieved by using [[(ngModel)]](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel)

ngmodel implements two-way data binding

in HTML

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (change)="onChange($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let action of actions" [ngValue]="action.id">{{action.name}}</option>
</select>
```

in ts

```
selectedValue : 0;



onchange(event){
console.log(event);
this.selectedvalue = event.value //your selcted value.
}
```

after opening your modal you can assign a selected value from dropdown to selectedValue variable in ts file which will allow you to see selected value in view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried this approach but not working.

Comment: using ngModel should work. I think you should look for some simple select example in angular for better implementation.

Comment: I have observed one thing in this approach, first time when we select an option from drop down list while opening the model, that time selectedValue getting updated to initial stage. But If I select again one more option by that time selectedValue not getting updated. If you have any idea please look on it once.

Comment: at the time of selecting a dropdown you can call a function on select element (change)="onChange($event)"  and assign the latest value of selected id to selectedValue; so whenever you select something it will bind that value to selectedValue. i have updated my answer you can check.

Comment: current selected value getting updated with your first approach it self. But which I am expecting is when I close the selected model, my drop down  list should show initial one, not current selected option. After closing every model my drop down should show intitial one only i.e "Select operation".

Comment: for that on closing modal function reset selectedvalue to 0 like this.selectedvalue = 0;

Comment: Tried bro, not working. But any how thank you soo much for your response.

Answer (score 0):

use `[(ngModel)]="selectedOption"` for two way binding and display operationwhen condition match `*ngIf="selectedOption==1"`

**[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-set-default-first-item-in-drop-down-list-angular-2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

```
<div class="bx--col-md-1">
     <select id="select-menu" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" class="bx--text-input" required name="actionSelection" (change)="onActionChange($event)" (dblclick)="onActionChange($event)">             
         <option  *ngFor="let action of actions"  [value]="action.id">{{action.name}}</option>
     </select>  

    <carbon-modal [modalId]= "modalid" [modalTitle]= "modaltitle" [isFull]="isFull" >
    <div modal-body>
    <div *ngIf="selectedOption==1">
        <Operation1></Operation1>   
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="selectedOption==2">
        <Operation2></Operation2>   
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="selectedOption==3">
        <Operation3></Operation3>       
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="selectedOption==4">
        <Operation4></Operation4>   
    </div>
  </div>
```

> ts file

```
selectedOption=0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried this approach but not working.

Comment: check Stackblitz demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-set-default-first-item-in-drop-down-list-angular-2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Normal drop down list selecting items and all working fine for me.But which I am expecting is, In my drop down list each operation contains different model is their, so when I select a operation that particular model window will open. After when we close that window my drop down list should show "Select operation" item, not current selected item.

Answer (score 0):

Use ngModel on the select field

**in template**

```
<select id="select-menu" class="bx--text-input" required name="actionSelection" 
(change)="onActionChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectionValue" 
(dblclick)="onActionChange($event)">             
 <option  *ngFor="let action of actions"  [value]="action.id">{{action.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

**In .ts file**

```
onActionChange($event) {
 // alert($event.target.value);
    // your previous code
       this.selectionValue = 0;  //this will set the select field value to the default
   }
```

**Note: selectedValue must have been declared as a component variable**

Comment: Perfect, Thank you soo much. But Initially it should show "Select Operation" now it is not coming.

Comment: set selectedValue to 0 when declaring it. so the defult is "Select Operation"

Comment: Yeah sure, But if I declare selectedValue=0 initially, After closing the model also it is not effecting.

Comment: Which you specified that approach effecting only first attempt i.e If i select Operation1 first time selectdValue get updating and If I select again Operation1 once again that selectedValue not getting updated. If you have any idea please look on it once.

Comment: Can you recreate this issue on stackblitz so I look into it properly

Comment: Sorry to tell you, I tried to put in stack blitz but their are lot of dependencies are their with child components and all. So I am unable to do this.